# Recyclerview with more than one views, Removing of addTextChangedListener() not working

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, listener

I am working on an android app where I am changing the some of `EditText`'s Value programmatically on manually change of `EditText`'s Value.

> - When user change the quantity I am changing the total price & sale price value.
> - When user change the sale price I am changing the discount value.
> - When user change the discount I am changing the sale price value.

[image]

I have added a `addTextChangedListener()` on every `EditText`. But before that I have created `TextWatcher` object for each `EditText`'s globally.

```
private TextWatcher quantityWatcher;
private TextWatcher priceWatcher;
private TextWatcher discountWatcher;
```

And define it `onBindViewHolder()` method, so whenever I want to remove or add a `TextChangedListener()` on it, I can do it easily.

Before changing the any EditText's values programmatically I am removing the `addTextChangedListener()` on every TextWatcher's objects by using `removeTextChangedListener()` to avoid calling the function by itself. After changing the value and registering back the listener on it.

**For Quantity EditText**

```
 quantityWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        Log.d("SocialCodia", "afterTextChanged: quantityWatcher Event Listener Called");
        quantityEvent(holder);
    }
};
```

**For Discount EditText.**

```
priceWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        Log.d("SocialCodia", "afterTextChanged: priceWatcher Event Listener Called");
        priceEvent(holder);
    }
};
```

**For Sale Price EditText**

```
discountWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        Log.d("SocialCodia", "afterTextChanged: discountWatcher Event Listener Called");
        discountInputEvent(holder);
    }
};
```

The method which I am calling on change of EditText's values.

```
private void priceEvent(ViewHolder holder) {
    Log.d("SocialCodia", "PriceEvent Method Called");
    unregisterTextWatcher(holder);
    int totalPrice = Integer.parseInt(holder.inputTotalPrice.getText().toString().trim());
    String sellPriceString = holder.inputSalePrice.getText().toString().trim();
    if (sellPriceString.trim().length()>0)
    {
        int sellPrice = Integer.parseInt(holder.inputSalePrice.getText().toString().trim());
        int discount = percentage(sellPrice, totalPrice);
        holder.inputSaleDiscount.setText(String.valueOf(discount));
    }
    else
    {
        holder.inputSaleDiscount.setText(String.valueOf(100));
    }
    registerTextWatchers(holder);
}

private void quantityEvent(ViewHolder holder)
{
    Log.d("SocialCodia", "quantityEvent Method Called");
    unregisterTextWatcher(holder);
    String quan = holder.inputSaleQuantity.getText().toString().trim();
    String per = holder.inputSaleDiscount.getText().toString().trim();
    int quantity;
    int percentage;
    if (quan == null || quan.length()<1 || quan.isEmpty())
        quantity = 1;
    else
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(quan);
    if (per==null || per.length()<1)
        percentage = 0;
    else
        percentage = Integer.parseInt(per);
    int price = Integer.parseInt(holder.tvProductPrice.getText().toString());
    int finalPrice = price*quantity;
    holder.inputTotalPrice.setText(String.valueOf(finalPrice));
    int salePrice = percentageDec(finalPrice,percentage);
    holder.inputSalePrice.setText(String.valueOf(salePrice));
    registerTextWatchers(holder);
}

private void discountInputEvent(ViewHolder holder) {
    Log.d("SocialCodia", "discountInputEvent Method Called");
    unregisterTextWatcher(holder);
    int totalPrice = Integer.parseInt(holder.inputTotalPrice.getText().toString().trim());
    String per = holder.inputSaleDiscount.getText().toString().trim();
    int percentage;
    if (per==null || per.length()<1)
        percentage = 0;
    else
        percentage = Integer.parseInt(per);
    int price = percentageDec(totalPrice, percentage);
    holder.inputSalePrice.setText(String.valueOf(price));
    registerTextWatchers(holder);
}

private int percentage(int partialValue, int totalValue) {
    Log.d("SocialCodia", "percentage Method Called");
    Double partial = (double) partialValue;
    Double total = (double) totalValue;
    Double per = (100 * partial) / total;
    Double p = 100 - per;
    return p.intValue();
}

private int percentageDec(int totalValue, int per) {
    Log.d("SocialCodia", "percentageDec Method Called");
    if (per == 0 || String.valueOf(per).length() < 0)
        return totalValue;
    else {
        Double total = (double) totalValue;
        Double perc = (double) per;
        Double price = (total - ((perc / 100) * total));
        Integer p = price.intValue();
        return p;
    }
}
```

Every conditions, logic, or method are working fine. But when I am inserting more than one views in `recyclerview`. Changing of any rows `EditText`'s value except the current inserted views calling the listener itself again and again.

[image: 0]

I have tried to figure out the exact issue but unable to do it.

**My Adapter Class `AdapterSaleEditable.java`**

```
public class AdapterSaleEditable extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterSaleEditable.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<ModelSale> modelSaleList;
    private String token;
    private SharedPrefHandler sp;
    private ModelUser user;
    private boolean discountFlag = false;
    private boolean priceEvenFlag = false;
    private TextWatcher quantityWatcher;
    private TextWatcher priceWatcher;
    private TextWatcher discountWatcher;

    public AdapterSaleEditable(Context context, List<ModelSale> modelSales) {
        this.context = context;
        this.modelSaleList = modelSales;
        sp = SharedPrefHandler.getInstance(context);
        user = sp.getUser();
        token = user.getToken();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_sale_editable, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ModelSale sale = modelSaleList.get(position);
        int productId = sale.getProductId();
        int saleId = sale.getSaleId();
        String productCategory = sale.getProductCategory();
        String productName = sale.getProductName();
        String productSize = sale.getProductSize();
        String productBrand = sale.getProductBrand();
        int productPrice = sale.getProductPrice();
        int productQuantity = sale.getProductQuantity();
        String productManufacture = sale.getProductManufacture();
        String productExpire = sale.getProductExpire();
        String createdAt = sale.getCreatedAt();

        holder.tvProductName.setText(productName);
        holder.tvProductSize.setText("(" + productSize + ")");
        holder.tvProductCategory.setText(productCategory);
        holder.tvProductPrice.setText(String.valueOf(productPrice));
        holder.inputTotalPrice.setText(String.valueOf(productPrice));
        holder.inputSaleQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(1));
        holder.inputSalePrice.setText(String.valueOf(productPrice));
        holder.inputSaleDiscount.setText(String.valueOf(0));
        holder.tvProductBrand.setText(productBrand);
        holder.tvProductManufacture.setText(productManufacture);
        holder.tvProductExpire.setText(productExpire);
        holder.tvCount.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));

        holder.cvSell.setOnLongClickListener(view -> {
            showDeleteAlert(holder, sale, position);
            return true;
        });


         quantityWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                Log.d("SocialCodia", "afterTextChanged: quantityWatcher Event Listener Called");
                quantityEvent(holder);
            }
        };


         priceWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                Log.d("SocialCodia", "afterTextChanged: priceWatcher Event Listener Called");
                priceEvent(holder);
            }
        };


         discountWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                Log.d("SocialCodia", "afterTextChanged: discountWatcher Event Listener Called");
                discountInputEvent(holder);
            }
        };


        registerTextWatchers(holder);
        //End on create method
    }

    private void registerTextWatchers(ViewHolder holder) {
        Log.d("SocialCodia", "Registring Listener");
        holder.inputSaleQuantity.addTextChangedListener(quantityWatcher);
        holder.inputSalePrice.addTextChangedListener(priceWatcher);
        holder.inputSaleDiscount.addTextChangedListener(discountWatcher);
    }

    private void unregisterTextWatcher(ViewHolder holder)
    {
        Log.d("SocialCodia", "UnRegistring Listener");
        holder.inputSaleQuantity.removeTextChangedListener(quantityWatcher);
        holder.inputSalePrice.removeTextChangedListener(priceWatcher);
        holder.inputSaleDiscount.removeTextChangedListener(discountWatcher);
    }


    private void priceEvent(ViewHolder holder) {
        Log.d("SocialCodia", "PriceEvent Method Called");
        unregisterTextWatcher(holder);
        int totalPrice = Integer.parseInt(holder.inputTotalPrice.getText().toString().trim());
        String sellPriceString = holder.inputSalePrice.getText().toString().trim();
        if (sellPriceString.trim().length()>0)
        {
            int sellPrice = Integer.parseInt(holder.inputSalePrice.getText().toString().trim());
            int discount = percentage(sellPrice, totalPrice);
            holder.inputSaleDiscount.setText(String.valueOf(discount));
        }
        else
        {
            holder.inputSaleDiscount.setText(String.valueOf(100));
        }
        registerTextWatchers(holder);
    }

    private void quantityEvent(ViewHolder holder)
    {
        Log.d("SocialCodia", "quantityEvent Method Called");
        unregisterTextWatcher(holder);
        String quan = holder.inputSaleQuantity.getText().toString().trim();
        String per = holder.inputSaleDiscount.getText().toString().trim();
        int quantity;
        int percentage;
        if (quan == null || quan.length()<1 || quan.isEmpty())
            quantity = 1;
        else
            quantity = Integer.parseInt(quan);
        if (per==null || per.length()<1)
            percentage = 0;
        else
            percentage = Integer.parseInt(per);
        int price = Integer.parseInt(holder.tvProductPrice.getText().toString());
        int finalPrice = price*quantity;
        holder.inputTotalPrice.setText(String.valueOf(finalPrice));
        int salePrice = percentageDec(finalPrice,percentage);
        holder.inputSalePrice.setText(String.valueOf(salePrice));
        registerTextWatchers(holder);
    }

    private void discountInputEvent(ViewHolder holder) {
        Log.d("SocialCodia", "discountInputEvent Method Called");
        unregisterTextWatcher(holder);
        int totalPrice = Integer.parseInt(holder.inputTotalPrice.getText().toString().trim());
        String per = holder.inputSaleDiscount.getText().toString().trim();
        int percentage;
        if (per==null || per.length()<1)
            percentage = 0;
        else
            percentage = Integer.parseInt(per);
        int price = percentageDec(totalPrice, percentage);
        holder.inputSalePrice.setText(String.valueOf(price));
        registerTextWatchers(holder);
    }

    private int percentage(int partialValue, int totalValue) {
        Log.d("SocialCodia", "percentage Method Called");
        Double partial = (double) partialValue;
        Double total = (double) totalValue;
        Double per = (100 * partial) / total;
        Double p = 100 - per;
        return p.intValue();
    }

    private int percentageDec(int totalValue, int per) {
        Log.d("SocialCodia", "percentageDec Method Called");
        if (per == 0 || String.valueOf(per).length() < 0)
            return totalValue;
        else {
            Double total = (double) totalValue;
            Double perc = (double) per;
            Double price = (total - ((perc / 100) * total));
            Integer p = price.intValue();
            return p;
        }
    }

    private void showDeleteAlert(ViewHolder holder, ModelSale sale, int position) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("Are you sure want to delete?");
        builder.setMessage("You are going to delete " + sale.getProductName() + ". The Sale Quantity of this product was " + sale.getSaleQuantity() + " and the total price was " + sale.getSalePrice());
        builder.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                deleteSoldProduct(sale.getSaleId(), position);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Deletion Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    private void deleteSoldProduct(int sellId, int position) {
        Call<ResponseDefault> call = ApiClient.getInstance().getApi().deleteSoldProduct(sellId, token);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseDefault>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseDefault> call, Response<ResponseDefault> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    ResponseDefault responseDefault = response.body();
                    if (!responseDefault.isError()) {
                        TastyToast.makeText(context, responseDefault.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, TastyToast.SUCCESS);
                        Helper.playSuccess();
                        Helper.playVibrate();
                        modelSaleList.remove(position);
                        notifyItemRemoved(position);
                        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, modelSaleList.size());
                    } else
                        TastyToast.makeText(context, responseDefault.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, TastyToast.ERROR);
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Request Isn't Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseDefault> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    public void updateList(List<ModelSale> list) {
        modelSaleList = list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return modelSaleList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvProductName, tvProductSize, tvProductCategory, tvSaleTime, tvProductPrice, tvProductBrand, tvProductManufacture, tvProductExpire, tvCount;
        private EditText inputSaleQuantity, inputSaleDiscount, inputSalePrice, inputTotalPrice;
        private CardView cvSell;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvProductName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductName);
            tvProductSize = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductSize);
            tvProductCategory = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductCategory);
            tvSaleTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSaleTime);
            tvProductPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductPrice);
            inputSaleQuantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.inputSaleQuantity);
            inputSaleDiscount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.inputSaleDiscount);
            inputSalePrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.inputSalePrice);
            tvProductBrand = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductBrand);
            tvProductManufacture = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductManufacture);
            tvProductExpire = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductExpire);
            inputTotalPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.inputTotalPrice);
            tvCount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCount);
            cvSell = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvSell);
        }
    }
}
```

My Fragment. From Where I am setting the recyclerview. `SellProductFragment.java`

```
public class SellProductActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView ivCloseDialog;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private EditText inputSearchProduct;
    private static List<ModelProduct> modelProductList;
    private AdapterProductSale adapterProductSale;
    private int productId;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sell_product);
        init();
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Sell Product");

        setRecyclerView();

        inputSearchProduct.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                filter(editable.toString());
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_close,menu);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id==R.id.miClose)
        {
            onBackPressed();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void filter(String text)
    {
        List<ModelProduct> p = new ArrayList<>();
        for(ModelProduct sale : modelProductList)
        {
            if (sale.getProductName().toLowerCase().trim().contains(text.toLowerCase()))
            {
                p.add(sale);
            }
        }
        adapterProductSale.updateList(p);
    }

    private void setRecyclerView() {
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        modelProductList = DbHandler.getModelProductList();
        adapterProductSale = new AdapterProductSale(SellProductActivity.this, modelProductList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterProductSale);
    }


    private void init() {
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvProducts);
        inputSearchProduct = findViewById(R.id.inputSearchProduct);
        modelProductList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

How can I solve the issue.

-Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I am inserting more than one views in recyclerview. Changing of any rows EditText's value except the current inserted views calling the listener itself again and again.

Well, the main issue of listener replication over and over again, that theses listeners exist in `onBindViewHolder()` as this method gets called every time a `RecyclerView` row is going to be displayed/recycled/changed/inserted on the screen; and that apparently happened whenever you added new items.

So, the possible way is to register these listeners somewhere else that going to be called once, or whenever you want to; i.e. not every time the rows are recycled.

You can do that in the `ViewHolder` constructor to the `EditText's` themselves.

**Challenge:** how can we know which `EditText` that the user modified? .. As if some `EditText` is modified and you recycled the views (i.e. scrolled up/down the list), you will see the value is messed up in multiple rows.

This can be solved by:

- Tracking the `EditText` values in your model class `ModelSale`.. Not
  sure if you already did that or not.. anyways this class should have
  fields, getters, & setters correspond to the `EditTexts` fields which
  we have (`quantity`, `discount`, & `price`). And these fields should
  be set in the `onBindViewHoder()` to get the saved values whenever
  the rows are recycled.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ModelSale sale = modelSaleList.get(position);

        // ...... rest of your code
        
        holder.unregisterTextWatcher();
        
        holder.inputSaleQuantity.setText(sale.getQuantatiy());
        holder.inputSaleDiscount.setText(sale.getDiscount());
        holder.inputSalePrice.setText(sale.getPrice());
        
        holder.registerTextWatchers();

        //End on create method
    }
```

- Getting the current item in the `ViewHolder` using `getAdapterPostion()`

And this approach requires to move all the watchers, fields, & methods that are related to `EditText` watchers from the `RecyclerViewAdapter` to the `ViewHolder`

And every time before changing these `EditTexts` fields, you need to unregsiter the text Watchers.

And here's the adapter only with those modifications in order to be compact.

```
public class AdapterSaleEditable extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterSaleEditable.ViewHolder> {

   // ... your code

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ModelSale sale = modelSaleList.get(position);

        // ...... rest of your code
        
        holder.unregisterTextWatcher();
        
        holder.inputSaleQuantity.setText(sale.getQuantatiy());
        holder.inputSaleDiscount.setText(sale.getDiscount());
        holder.inputSalePrice.setText(sale.getPrice());
        
        holder.registerTextWatchers();

        //End on create method
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvProductName, tvProductSize, tvProductCategory, tvSaleTime, tvProductPrice, tvProductBrand, tvProductManufacture, tvProductExpire, tvCount;
        private EditText inputSaleQuantity, inputSaleDiscount, inputSalePrice, inputTotalPrice;
        private CardView cvSell;

        private TextWatcher quantityWatcher;
        private TextWatcher priceWatcher;
        private TextWatcher discountWatcher;

        private void registerTextWatchers() {
            Log.d("SocialCodia", "Registring Listener");
            inputSaleQuantity.addTextChangedListener(quantityWatcher);
            inputSalePrice.addTextChangedListener(priceWatcher);
            inputSaleDiscount.addTextChangedListener(discountWatcher);
        }

        private void unregisterTextWatcher() {
            Log.d("SocialCodia", "UnRegistring Listener");
            inputSaleQuantity.removeTextChangedListener(quantityWatcher);
            inputSalePrice.removeTextChangedListener(priceWatcher);
            inputSaleDiscount.removeTextChangedListener(discountWatcher);
        }

        private void priceEvent() {
            Log.d("SocialCodia", "PriceEvent Method Called");
            unregisterTextWatcher();
            int totalPrice = Integer.parseInt(inputTotalPrice.getText().toString().trim());
            String sellPriceString = inputSalePrice.getText().toString().trim();
            if (sellPriceString.trim().length() > 0) {
                int sellPrice = Integer.parseInt(inputSalePrice.getText().toString().trim());
                int discount = percentage(sellPrice, totalPrice);
                inputSaleDiscount.setText(String.valueOf(discount));
            } else {
                inputSaleDiscount.setText(String.valueOf(100));
            }
            registerTextWatchers();
        }

        private void quantityEvent() {
            Log.d("SocialCodia", "quantityEvent Method Called");
            unregisterTextWatcher();
            String quan = inputSaleQuantity.getText().toString().trim();
            String per = inputSaleDiscount.getText().toString().trim();
            int quantity;
            int percentage;
            if (quan == null || quan.length() < 1 || quan.isEmpty())
                quantity = 1;
            else
                quantity = Integer.parseInt(quan);
            if (per == null || per.length() < 1)
                percentage = 0;
            else
                percentage = Integer.parseInt(per);
            int price = Integer.parseInt(tvProductPrice.getText().toString());
            int finalPrice = price * quantity;
            inputTotalPrice.setText(String.valueOf(finalPrice));
            int salePrice = percentageDec(finalPrice, percentage);
            inputSalePrice.setText(String.valueOf(salePrice));
            registerTextWatchers();
        }

        private void discountInputEvent() {
            Log.d("SocialCodia", "discountInputEvent Method Called");
            unregisterTextWatcher();
            int totalPrice = Integer.parseInt(inputTotalPrice.getText().toString().trim());
            String per = inputSaleDiscount.getText().toString().trim();
            int percentage;
            if (per == null || per.length() < 1)
                percentage = 0;
            else
                percentage = Integer.parseInt(per);
            int price = percentageDec(totalPrice, percentage);
            inputSalePrice.setText(String.valueOf(price));
            registerTextWatchers();
        }

        private int percentage(int partialValue, int totalValue) {
            Log.d("SocialCodia", "percentage Method Called");
            Double partial = (double) partialValue;
            Double total = (double) totalValue;
            Double per = (100 * partial) / total;
            Double p = 100 - per;
            return p.intValue();
        }

        private int percentageDec(int totalValue, int per) {
            Log.d("SocialCodia", "percentageDec Method Called");
            if (per == 0 || String.valueOf(per).length() < 0)
                return totalValue;
            else {
                Double total = (double) totalValue;
                Double perc = (double) per;
                Double price = (total - ((perc / 100) * total));
                Integer p = price.intValue();
                return p;
            }
        }

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            
            // Rest of your code

            // Text Watchers
            
            quantityWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                    Log.d("SocialCodia", "afterTextChanged: quantityWatcher Event Listener Called");
                    quantityEvent();
                }
            };

            priceWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                    Log.d("SocialCodia", "afterTextChanged: priceWatcher Event Listener Called");
                    priceEvent();
                }
            };


            discountWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                    Log.d("SocialCodia", "afterTextChanged: discountWatcher Event Listener Called");
                    discountInputEvent();
                }
            };

            registerTextWatchers();

        }
    }
}
```